# GitHub - How to visually see file differences between two branches?

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

I have a project on github with two branches (dev and master), where code was in sync prior to adding some new features to dev. For a few months, I've been adding new features on the dev branch, which consisted of changes/updates to existing files, deleting some files, and creating new files, all on the dev branch. Everything is working great on the dev branch and now it's time to apply these changes  to the master branch.

Since there are a lot of changes, I am trying to see all the differences visually between the dev and master branches, so I can apply the specific changes from dev to master without missing anything. I don't want to override master with dev, as there are some master specific files, so just the new things in dev should be applied to master, but I want to do it where I can see the compared files visually to ensure everything is looking right.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new branch from `develop` named `release/may6`. This way, you can commit changes to `release/may6` without actually impacting your `master` branch.

Commit any master-specific differences to `release/may6` and use the GitHub `compare` UI to see the differences between your working `release/may6` branch and `master`:

```
https://github.com/orgname/reponame/compare/master...release/may6
```

Once you are satisfied that this view shows the correct master-only differences between `release/may6` and `master`, simply create a Pull Request from that same compare UI which merges `release/may6` into `master`.

Comment: Can you compare two commits to the same branch this way?

Comment: Yep - just get both commits' hashes and plug them into the /compare/ URI like so: `/compare/<hash1>...<hash2>`. You can find commit hashes in the Commits tab.